# Additional Parameters with c# registry

Tags: c#

This is my current code:

```
RegistryKey registryKey = Registry.CurrentUser.OpenSubKey("SOFTWARE\\Microsoft\\Windows\\CurrentVersion\\Run", true);
                registryKey.SetValue("Programname", Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.ApplicationData));
```

There are no errors or anything with this however it does not point to my program. Instead Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.ApplicationData) points to my AppData folder (as expected). However how am I suppose to point it to an executable in that folder?

I'm using C# 2.0

Comment: unless the question is not clear, Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.ApplicationData) is showing only the folder so you need to concat ExcutableName.exe (your program)

Answer (score 0):

you need to use

```
System.Diagnostics.Process.GetCurrentProcess().MainModule.FileName
```

OR

```
System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetName().CodeBase
```

to get the path..

So it would be:

```
RegistryKey registryKey = Registry.CurrentUser.OpenSubKey("SOFTWARE\\Microsoft\\Windows\\CurrentVersion\\Run", true);
                registryKey.SetValue("Programname", System.Diagnostics.Process.GetCurrentProcess().MainModule.FileName);
```

Comment: Isn't that only using the executable name of the main file?

Comment: @user1372896 use `System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetName().CodeBase` instead then.